# How do I insert a sentence into a string at a specific location?

Tags: python

Let's say there is a line like this:

```
<a href="//gifts.ru/catalog/model-futbolka-imperial"> Imperial 190 </a> is a premium model, decoration of any promotion and a worthy personal gift. Soft, comfortable tight T-shirt, with a collar protected from deformation. It holds its shape perfectly and is ideal for applying a logo. The absence of side seams allows you to apply the image almost over the entire surface. <br>
```

Tell me how this can be done? I wanted to do `find ('.')`, But it won't work, since the dot is also in the link

```
<a href="//gifts.ru/catalog/model-futbolka-imperial"> Imperial 190 </a>
```

Expected output:

```
<a href="//gifts.ru/catalog/model-futbolka-imperial"> Imperial 190 </a> is a premium model, decoration of any promotion and a worthy personal gift. **[INSERTED TEXT]**. Soft, comfortable tight T-shirt, with a collar protected from deformation. It holds its shape perfectly and is ideal for applying a logo. The absence of side seams allows you to apply the image almost over the entire surface. <br>
```

There will be a lot of such insertions.

Comment: Can you more clearly show us the input and expected output?

Comment: @Ekzo looks like you append a string to the original string. You add `is a premium model ...` to the original string - isnt it?

Comment: @balderman No, this is a parsed string. I need to insert a line after the first sentence on this line!

Comment: @Ekzo I've posted an answer, let me know if it does what you wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first find the index of the first `.` which occurs after the `</a>` and append the text which you want to insert with the help of slicing. However, this depends on the assumption that the main text is always coming after an anchor tag....

```
text = "Text to be inserted."
to_parse = '<a href="//gifts.ru/catalog/model-futbolka-imperial"> Imperial 190 </a> is a premium model, decoration of any promotion and a worthy personal gift. Soft, comfortable tight T-shirt, with a collar protected from deformation. It holds its shape perfectly and is ideal for applying a logo. The absence of side seams allows you to apply the image almost over the entire surface. <br>'

index = to_parse.find(".", to_parse.find("</a>"))
to_parse = to_parse[:index+1] + text + to_parse[index+1:]
print(to_parse)
```

You can adjust the spacing and/or fullstops which come before or after the inserted text as per your requirement by editing the slicing statement.